# Wicket: Conditional Validator

Tags: validation, wicket

I have a form whose inputs are required in certain combinations, and also depending on which submit button was clicked.

E.g. fields A, B, and C, and submit buttons M, N. And valid combinations are
M: A + B
N: A + B + C
N: A
N: C

So none of inputs are always required.

Currently I solve it using if( ... ) in `onSubmit()`, but I wonder: Could I move these checks to a per-component validator with a callback which would (dis)approve certain combination?

*Update:*

```
_______________________

  User name:  ______
  Password:   ______

  [ Log in button ]

  Email:      ______

  [ Register / reset password button ]
_______________________
```

Login needs user name and password.
Register needs all, in which case it registers,
or just mail, or just user name, in which case it sends a pass reset challenge mail.

Comment: Did you look at IFormValidator? It allows you the specify dependencies. But it doesn't solve the problem that validations are different depending on the button clicked.

Comment: I'd like to reuse the existing validators, but "activate" them depending on those conditions. Maybe I could chain them behind my impl.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the example over at https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/conditional-validation.html, it should pretty much solve your problem:

```js
Button submit = new Button("submit") {
    public void onSubmit() {
        // handle form submission
    }
}
form.add(submit);

TextField foo = new TextField("foo") {
    public boolean isRequired() {
        Form form = (Form) findParent(Form.class);
        return form.getRootForm().findSubmittingButton() == button;
    }
}
form.add(foo);
```

Let me know if you need any further help or if it's not working. Cheers

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as resolved if it did? Would help me out as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you add AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehaviors to your components and then disable all components which shouldn't be available in the current combination via

```
formComponent.setEnabled(false);
target.add(formComponent);
```

Disabled components will not be considered in validation. An additional benefit is, that the user always has feedback on allowed combinations immediately.

Comment: +1, but unfurtunately, that's not an option for my situation, see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the form looks like so:

```
TextField user = new TextField();
user.setRequired(true);
TextField pass = new TextField();
TextField email = new TextField();
Button login = new Button();
Button register = new Button();
```

I would try creating a FormValidator class like so:

```
public class MyValidator extends AbstractFormValidator
{
   private FormComponent[3] fields;

   public MyValidtor(TextField field1, TextField, field2, Button button)
   {
      fields = {field1, field2, button };
   }

   //getDependentFormComponents returns fields;

   public void validate(Form form)
   {
      if ( form.getRootForm().findSubmittingButton() == button)
      {
         //do field1 & field2 required checks here
      } 
   }
}
```

then just Add `MyValidator` to your form

```
form.add(new MyValidator(user, pass,  login));
form.add(new MyValidator(user, email, register));
```